# How do I set up a narrow path through a firewall to access Notes in xpages?

Tags: xpages, administration

I am not an admin, I'm a developer so admin is kind of foreign to me.  I am developing an intranet for a company in xpages and client.  There are a handful of people who are not in the company who need to get through the firewall via VPN.  The admin guys at the company are not Notes admins.  Some "company" users will use the apps locally at times and through the internet at times because there may not be internet access at trade shows where they are using the system.  I need all the steps to perform that sets up the access in Notes and a guide to give the admins to allow VPN to allow these users access to Notes.  Like I said, I'm not an admin so I need explicit explanations or someone who may be able to contact an admin at the company.  Please help.  This includes authentication help as I have not done that yet either.

Comment: It sounds like this has nothing to do with XPages.  XPages would just need an http port redirected to the domino server.  Is this more about getting the Notes Client to connect past the firewall?  Or maybe XPage in the notes client?  I kinda think this is too big a question to be effective on StackOverFlow but I guess first there should be more clarity in what you want.

Comment: I agree with David. In general: use port 1352 for Notes client access and port 80 and port 443 for web/XPages access

Comment: You also need to make sure your Domino server is secure before you open it up. You should be using SSL and the later fix packs (FP 5 or 6 and newer) with 9.0.1. The login page should never be accessible via http, only https. Preferably all the apps will use https (database property)

Comment: While this question is a an admin question, a very important part is still missing: Which vendor / product are you using? By the way, this is a very, very , very, very security relevant topic. The setup of a VPN must be done by someone with the knowledge of configuring your VPN and your infrastructure, not by stepping through a short tutorial from the internet...

Comment: They already have Sonic VPN set up to access their network.  I am writing the app in xpages but have had to test it all on localhost.  I'm nearing the end of the first phase and need to access it through a browser at this point but they don't have the expertise to set it up on the Notes side and I don't have the admin experience or normal admin experience to do it either.  I appreciate your comments.  Users can't access Notes through a firewall directly on the internet can they?  They have to go through VPN?  How to set up the ports/configuration????